# How to move entire report footer of crystal report to last page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in VS19 where I want to move my entire report footer to the last page if the report have multiple pages. Currently what is happening is, if my report have multiple pages, report footer will appear in the 1st page itself and accommodate as much of controls it can there and move the rest of the section to the last page. I have tried a lot of things such as adding formula to suppress the report footer if
`pagenumber <> totalpagecount`
then tried adding new page before with the same above formula. but nothing was working properly. If i applied new page like this it will forcefully make the reports 2 paged which is actually not needed and behave according to the formula. What I exactly needed is , if the detail section has more data such that it will make the report overflowing to make it 2 paged,  then only the **entire** **Report Footer** should  appear in 2nd page/last page. Could anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Section Expert for report footer section, turn on the ***Keep Together*** checkbox.

Comment: It is already checked. but still keeping half of the controls in one page and rest in another